# Automated javascript and html testing over multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, testing, automated-tests

We have a webshop and we sell lots of items.
Our checkout process consists of 4 different pages where the user has to input their address, select a delivery method and confirm their order on different pages/urls. Each of those pages relies on communication with the server and lots of javascript / jquery.

Some of our users have reported problems at some parts of those pages. We suspect it could be a combination of OS/browser that can't understand a part of our javascript code.

**Is there any way to automate testing of a checkout process of 4 different consecutive pages, each requiring user input?** 
We would like the testing environment to test on different brosers/browser versions. 
We also had a customer recently that had an antivirus program that would change the urls of our js source files, is there any way to capture cases like that by testing?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might use [E2E testing](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/7035/end-to-end-test), using [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/)/[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

It's basically about writing user behaviour, and the browser driver does it instead of user. You can write what should happen on the page and if any of these conditions is not met, it will be included in the post-test report. You can configure it to use whatever browser driver you like.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). The main purpose of it is to automate browsers actions.